# Using Json, Data Not Displayed In Grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

Using one method i am performing all crud operation,
Controller Code :-

```
public JsonResult AddEmployee(EmployeeModel Emp)
        {
            #region Object Declaration

        SqlConnection connection = null;

        SqlCommand com = null;

        DataSet ds = null;

        #endregion

        try
        {
            // Get Connection string
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

            // Set sql connection 
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            // Set sql commands
            com = new SqlCommand("SP_tblInsertEmployee_Insert", connection);

            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", Emp.EmployeeName);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", Emp.Designation);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", Emp.MobileNo);

            connection.Open();

            int a = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            //Code For GetData
            com = new SqlCommand("SP_tblInsertEmployee_SelectAllDatabyID", connection);

            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID",a);

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            da.SelectCommand = com;

            ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);

            int c = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            #region Release Object

            connection = null;

            com = null;

            #endregion
        }

        return Json(ds,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JavaScript Code:-

```
function Bind_EmployeeDetails_Grid(data)
{



$("#tblEmployeeDetails").html("");

var htmltext = "";

$("txtEmployeeID").val(data.Emp.EmployeeID),

$("txtEmployeeName").val(data.Emp.EmployeeName),

$("txtDesignation").val(data.Emp.Designation),

$("txtMobileNo").val(data.Emp.MobileNo)

if(data.Emp.length > 0)
{
    htmltext += "<tr>";

    htmltext += "<th>EmployeeID</th>";

    htmltext += "<th>EmployeeName</th>";

    htmltext += "<th>Designation</th>";

    htmltext += "<th>MobileNo</th>";

    htmltext += "</tr>";

}
for(i=0; i<data.Emp.length; i++)
{

    htmlText += "<tr>";

    htmlText += "<td>";

    htmlText += data.Emp[i].EmployeeID == null ? "" : data.Emp[i].EmployeeID;

    htmlText += "</td>";

    htmlText += "<td>";

    htmlText += data.Emp[i].EmployeeName == null ? "" : data.Emp[i].EmployeeName;

    htmlText += "</td>";

    htmlText += "<td>";

    htmlText += data.Emp[i].Designation == null ? "" : data.Emp[i].Designation;

    htmlText += "</td>";

    htmlText += "<td>";

    htmlText += data.Emp[i].MobileNo == null ? "" : data.Emp[i].MobileNo;

    htmlText += "</td>";
}

$('#tblEmployeeDetails').html(htmltext);

  //  ClearData();
}
```

Comment: you aren't closing your `<tr>` with a `</tr>` in the second loop. That could be an issue

Comment: Your Web method returns a `DataSet` as json. And in javascript you are trying to access `data.Emp`, Does your DataSet contain a table named `Emp`?